# How to apply .astype() method to a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert multiple columns in a dataframe (pandas) to the type "category" using the method `.astype`. Here is my code:

```
df['Field_1'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

works however

```
categories = df.select_types('objects')
categories['Field_1'].cat.codes
```

doesn't.

Would someone please tell my why?
In general, the question is how to apply a method (.astype) to a dataframe? I know how to apply a method to a column in a dataframe, however, applying it to a dataframe hasnt been successful, even with `for` loop since the `for` loop returns a series and the method `.cat.codes` is not appliable for the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need processing each column separately in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and lambda function, your code failed, because [`Series.cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html) is not implemented for `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('acbdac'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':list('dddbbb')
})

cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  1
2  1  4  9  1
3  3  5  4  0
4  0  5  2  0
5  2  4  3  0
```

Similar idea, not sure if same output if convert all columns to categorical in first step by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype('category').apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  1
2  1  4  9  1
3  3  5  4  0
4  0  5  2  0
5  2  4  3  0
```